# How to return an array from `capture` with `global` filter in `jq`

Tags: jq

Given the following input:

```json
{
  "text": "a1\nb2"
}
```

How do I get the following output:

```json
[
  {
    "letter": "a",
    "number": 1
  },
  {
    "letter": "b",
    "number": 2
  }
]
```

I've tried using `capture` with the `"g"` flag, but this yields two documents instead of a single document with an array of captured inputs:

```bash
$ echo '{
  "text": "a1\\nb2"
}' | jq '.text | capture("(?<letter>[a-z])(?<number>[0-9])";"g")'
{
  "letter": "a",
  "number": "1"
}
{
  "letter": "b",
  "number": "2"
}
```

Here is a [link](https://jqplay.org/s/Z4U5mzPkav-) to the jqplay example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just wrap the `capture` in a new array:

```
.text | [ capture("(?<letter>[a-z])(?<number>[0-9])";"g") ]
```

##### [JqPlay](https://jqplay.org/s/tvut-TPC7yS)